# Mod $l$ algebraic $K$-theory of product of an algebra with a complete algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, algebraic-k-theory, motivic-cohomology

By Gabber's rigidity the mod-$l$ $K$-theory of $k[[t]]$ and $k$ are isomorphic for a field $k$. Is there anything that we can say about the mod $l$ $K$-theory of $A\otimes_kk[[t]]$? Note that this is not complete and does not form a henselian pair with respect to the ideal generated by $t$. How about mod $l$ etale $K$-theory? (this is related to etale cohomology with coefficients in $\mu_l$).

I think I figured out a proof for the etale case, if the $A$ is replaced by a proper scheme (so it does not work on affines). Please let me know if it is not correct.

**Proposition.** Let $(A,I)$ be a henselian pair. We define $A_0:=A/I$. Let $X$ be a proper scheme over $\text{Spec}(A)$ and denote $X_0=X\times_{\text{Spec}(A)}\text{Spec}(A_0)$. Then for any $l$-torsion sheaf $F$ we have an isomorphism of etale cohomology groups:
$$H^i(X,F)\cong H^i(X_0,F|_{X_0})$$
Proof: I found this in [here](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/%7Eybilu/algant/documents/theses/Pippi.pdf). Check Lemma 6.1.6 and Proposition 6.2.3. (The results seem to be original, please let me know if there are other sources for this proposition.)

Now we have the etale motivic spectral sequence in the following form:
$$E^{p,q}_2=H_{et}^p(Y, \mu_l^{\otimes (-q/2)})\Rightarrow K^{et}_{-p-q}/l(Y)$$
By the proposition the second page of the spectral sequence for $X$ and $X_0$ are isomorphic so implies that pullback induces isomorphism on the etale $K$-theory mod $l$.

Comment: Lemma 6.1.6 has a very important properness assumption. I'm slightly doubtful that a statement of the form you are looking for can be true.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the properness condition.